# Why is Webgl 3D not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webgl

I am currently working for this startup. They are using Webgl for 3D graphics in their product. When I run it in Chrome, it rarely gives the 3D effects. I have enabled webgl in Chrome (Version 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit) ) but still there is no luck. However when I run it in Mozilla Firefox,the 3D graphics runs perfectly. 
Here is the website - 
http://pro.4d-life.com/ . 
Username - example@4d-life.net
Password - 12345678

What I need to know is why is this happening and/or how to fix this? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## Try these out for troubleshooting :

1. Check to see if you’re using a supported operating system.
2. Check to see if you’re using an unsupported graphics card (check the Khronos wiki for a list of supported cards).
3. Check to see if WebGL is turned on by typing **chrome://gpu/** in your Chrome browser.
4. If WebGL is unavailable, check the "Problems Detected" section for information on why WebGL might be turned off.
5. If the "Problems Detected" section lists an issue with your graphics driver, make sure your graphics card driver and OS system is up to date.

Check to see if you're using the latest version of Google Chrome by going to About Google Chrome.

WebGL :

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have turned on `Use hardware acceleration when available`.

- `chrome://settings/system`
  [image: chrome-system]